# How to generate software reliability reports

Tags: test-management, manual-testing, load-testing, bug-report, test-report

We have are developing software application and we have developed about 80% of application and also tested. Now, for pilot launching, we required software reliability reports. Does anyone have any idea about how to generate software reliability report and what are the areas which we need to cover in this report? I have never created such report and I need to submit it to my management team in a day or two.

Can anyone help me out finding sample report.

I would appreciate your inputs/help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of any standard definition for "Software Reliability Report". And an internet search doesn't show anything either.

So you have 2 options:

1. Ask management what they want in the report, or if they don't know, ask them what the report is for and use your best judgement.
2. Make something up. List of known defects, supported usage scenarios, unsupported scenarios, working features, missing features, etc.

Out of these 2 options, the first one is preferable, unless you have unreasonable management.

Comment: I totally agree with Peter. It is always best to ask the stakeholder what information they are looking for that will help them make informed decision!